# why do I keep getting "undefined" with MySQL function?

Tags: javascript, mysql

When using one of my functions:

```js
    async function fetchServerChance(serverID) {
    var returnValue;
    con.query("SELECT chance FROM serversConfigs WHERE serverID = '"+serverID+"' LIMIT 1", function (err, rows) {
     if (err) throw err;
     returnValue = (rows[0].chance);
    });
    return returnValue;
}
```

```js
console.log(await fetchServerChance(message.guild.id));
```

It only returns "undefined", somebody please explain what in god's name I am suppose to do. I've tried doing tons of things like `return await returnValue;` and making some of the other lines have `await` in them.

Comment: Solve all your problems, including ones you don't yet know you have, by reading this: https://Bobby-tables.com

Comment: Do not use var. if query is async too, then wait for it to finish before trying to return values it gives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code works like this

```
async function fetchServerChance(serverID) {
    var returnValue; // 1
    con.query("SELECT chance FROM serversConfigs WHERE serverID = '"+serverID+"' LIMIT 1", function (err, rows) {
     if (err) throw err;
     returnValue = (rows[0].chance); // 4
    }); // 2
    return returnValue; // 3
}
```

1 - `returnValue` declared at the top of function and it's value is `undefined`

2 - con.query() is calling MySQL (but returns right-away and will call provided function when results will be ready)

3 - function returns `undefined` which is current value of `returnValue`

4 - (some time later) `returnValue` gets updated to result of a query (but nothing gets to use that value)

You can't change the order of above execution. `con.query()` is asynchronous but does not return a Promise to you (so you can't stop execution there and `await` for the result). The function needs to return something while it does not have the result yet.

You can wrap `con.query()` into a Promise and return it. This will bridge the gap between MySQL library API (that accepts callback functions) and will allow to use async/await approach.

```
async function fetchServerChance(serverID) {
    const returnValue = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      con.query(
        // serverID value will be escaped for safety and put into ? placeholder
        // see https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values
        "SELECT chance FROM serversConfigs WHERE serverID = ? LIMIT 1", [serverID], 
        function (err, rows) {
            // promise will be rejected if error happens (async function can catch the error with try/catch clause
            if (err) { reject(err) };
            // promise will resolve to value of chance
            resolve(rows[0].chance); 
        }
      );
    });
    return returnValue; // promise of future value
}
```

P.S.

More information about Promises: [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [Making asynchronous programming easier with async and await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

P.S.

It's a common issue, so there is [`promise-mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) library which does the above (returns Promises) and allows MySQL queries to be re-written as `const rows = await con.query("QUERY")`